# Highchart java script getting filled

Tags: javascript, csv, highcharts

Hello i have a javascript generating a highchart from a csv file:

```
<script>
                function Showgraph(){
                    $.ajax({
                         url: 'Merge_files.php',
                         // success: function(data) {
                         // $('.result').html(data);
                         // alert('Load was performed.');
                       // }
                    });
                    var options = {
                        chart: {
                            renderTo: 'container',
                            defaultSeriesType: 'line'
                        },
                        title: {
                            text: 'Measurement data'
                        },
                        xAxis: {
                            //categories: [],
                            title: {
                                text: 'Measurement number'
                                },
                                labels: {
                                    enable: false,
                                y:20, rotation: -45, allign: 'right'
                                }
                        },
                        yAxis: {
                            title: {
                                text: 'Retro Reflection'
                            }
                        },
                        series: []
                    };
                    sleep(100);
                    $.get('Sensor_datafull.txt', function(data) {
                        // Split the lines
                        var lines = data.split('\n');

                        $.each(lines, function(lineNo, line) {
                        var items = line.split(',');


                            var series = {
                                data: []
                            };
                            $.each(items, function(itemNo, item) {
                                if (itemNo == 0) {
                                    series.name = item;
                                } else {
                                    series.data.push(parseFloat(item));
                                }
                            });

                            options.series.push(series);


                        });

                        // Create the chart
                        var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
                    })
                }

<!--Sleep function to pause the Showgraph, so the fiels in Merge_files will be generated before chart -->

                function sleep(milliseconds) {
                  var start = new Date().getTime();
                  for (var i = 0; i < 1e7; i++) {
                    if ((new Date().getTime() - start) > milliseconds){
                      break;
                    }
                  }
                }

</script>
```

The script "merge" 7 files into one big and creates the chart. The files get filled with new measurement data each second. The merges file looks like:

0.20,-517.2,-314.9,227.2,....
0.33,-228.5,-79.0,130.7,....
0.50,-286.6,-140.6,84.5,....
0.70,-96.6,-62.6,23.0,....
1.00,-18.6,-12.4,11.6,....
1.50,-62.7,-35.9,-11.0,....
2.00,-37.7,-24.0,-1.5,....

The problem is that when the files reach a certain size the highchart cant be made and freezes instead. I was then wondering if it were possible to make high chart take only like the first data (is the category) and 500 last data of each line in a csv. file or something? any other ideas to fix the problem is also welcomed!

in advance thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: You could build a `series` with the entire CSV file and then using javascript create a subset of that `series` with however many values you want (e.g. first and last 500).

Answer (score 0):

At the beginning the problem is that you have incorrect architecture. You cannot use sleep function, because in case when your first ajax load longer, then furher code doenst' make sense. To avoid this situation you can call it once. In PHP file, prepare structure like arrays with data and transform it to JSON (by json_encode function). In javascrpt, call $.getJSON() and initialise your chart.